# Iterating through instances of a class by instance attribute

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a class called House and I want to make a number of instances of it that will be arranged visually in a grid:

```
class House(object):

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.rooms = 0
```

I want to iterate through all the instances of House in this grid by row and column:

```
for row in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
   for col in range(GRIDWIDTH):

      thisHouse = House()
      thisHouse.row = row
      thisHouse.col = col
```

and then later in the code I want to loop through the instances that have been created...

```
for row in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
   for col in range(GRIDWIDTH):

      ??? something something ??? 

         if thisHouse.room =< 1:
            do stuff
         else: 
            thisHouse.room = +1
      etc
```

The "??? something something ???" is where I'm not sure how to proceed, somehow instances of thisHouse must be searched through (by thisHouse.row and thisHouse.col I should think) until matched with the row and col in GRIDHEIGHT and GRIDWIDTH, hope that makes sense. I'm not sure how to do this, so far research indicates _dir() might be useful but seems to show the attributes but not the content of attributes.

Perhaps "??? something something ???" should be...

```
for thisHouse.row = row and thisHouse.col = col:
```

But I don't think this will work well. I am overhauling a big chunk of code here so can't just test this bit at this point, so advice appreciated.

Comment: so far, it looks to me like `thisHouse` is being overwritten in every iteration of the loops. Also to check if something is equal use `==` not `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, what you want to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
import itertools

class House(object):

    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self._row = row
        self._col = col

GRIDHEIGHT = 10
GRIDWIDTH = 10

houses = {(col, row): House(row, col) for col, row in 
          itertools.product(range(GRIDWIDTH), range(GRIDHEIGHT))}
```

alternatively you could also use double nested dictionaries:

```
houses = {col: {row: House(row, col) for row in range(GRIDHEIGHT)} for col in range(GRIDWIDTH)}
```

access to relevant house will be done via `houses[(col, row)]` or `houses[col][row]`:

```
for col in range(GRIDWIDTH):
    for row in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
       houses[col][row].foo() # or houses[(col, row)].foo()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks closest to the approach I'm currently trying to ram through.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you flip the problem? You are storing grid information on the House, instead of storing house/objects information on the grid.
You can have a 2D array representing the grid, then at each cell, you have the information you want, aka the object that are in that cell, it is up to you if to have a generic collection of object or separate them in like a dictionary where you have the tag house, pet, car.

Some psudo code:

```
for x in grid:
    for cell in x:
       #here you have the cell:
       for obj in cell.objs:
          if (obj is House):
             do stuff
```

Of course if you have more insight on what you want to do, and what element are there you can optimize you search inside the cell like:

```
for x in grid:
    for cell in x:
       #here you have the cell:
       for h in cell.objs["houses"]:
             do stuff
```

And of course you can still save coordinates information in the house class.
Laying your data this way will allow to easily iterate trough the houses even if distribution is not uniform and also it will allows to do operation like, find neighbors etc.